# Create connection line between edges and nodes in GraphViz

Tags: python, graphviz, decision-tree

I am looking for a way to create the following kind of graph in GraphViz

I would like to get the connection line, which goes from one edge to the others what you can see at an conjunction (marked in red)
[image]

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

For [dashed or dotted](http://www.tonyballantyne.com/graphs.html) try:

```
edge [ style="dashed" ]; // affects all edges
// or
A->B [style="dotted"];
```

The other part of drawing and edge between edges or an arrow pointing to an edge, may require placing an invisible node which is a point and removing the arrow head from the edge that points to it. It seems to still leave a break but it could work for dotted or dashed lines.

Approximately:

```
S_X [style="invis",shape="point"];
S_Y [style="invis",shape="point"];
S -> S_Y [arrowhead="none"];
S_Y -> Y;
S -> S_X [arrowhead="none"];
S_X -> X;
S_Y -> S_X [arrowhead="none"];
```

Comment: Actually a good idea, but unfortunately not _acceptable_ for my case...